# Change shapefile field names using ogr AlterFieldDefn

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, fields-attributes

I need to change field names of a shapefile to upper case using ogr. I want to do this automatically, versus calling out each field and replacing the name with upper case.  When I try to implement using layer AlterFieldlDefn, I get a TypeError. Here is the code I am using:

```
Shapefile = r"C:\test.shp"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open(Shapefile, 1) 

if dataSource is None:
    print 'Could not open %s' % (Shapefile)
else:
    print 'Opened %s' % (Shapefile)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
    layer_defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
    for i in range(layer_defn.GetFieldCount()):
        print layer_defn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName()
        uppercase_name = layer_defn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName().upper()
        layer.AlterFieldDefn(i, uppercase_name, 1)
```

The error I get is this:

> TypeError: in method 'Layer_AlterFieldDefn', argument 3 of type
>   'OGRFieldDefnShadow

How do I correctly uses AlterFieldDefn to change the field names to upper case?  I do not have ArcGIS 10.2, so AlterField_management is not an option.

Comment: You are starting a loop statement with your for statement but are not indenting for the lines after that.  Is this the way you have it formatted?

Comment: My mistake, those next lines are indented.  I corrected it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be missing some steps.  You need to use some additional methods like .CloneFieldDefn(), .SetName() method, and then use the .org.ALTER_NAME_FLAG value for the third parameter in the .AlterFieldDefn statement.  See link below for code reference (lines 97-103).

https://github.com/stefanct/OGD_Wien_tools/blob/master/FAHRRADABSTELLANLAGEOGD.py

Comment: That reference did help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Although this post is quite old, I was facing a similar problem and sloved it like this:

```
layerDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(layerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = layerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    fieldName = fieldDefn.GetName()
    fieldDefn.SetName(fieldName.upper())
```