# Change to field name of gpkg layer not retained using ogr

Tags: python, fields-attributes, ogr, geopackage

I am trying to update the names of the fields in a gpkg layer using the ogr Python package. I have gotten most of the way using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326864/200146) to another question on the subject using `SetName` on the `fieldDefn`:

```
    gpkg_layer = gpkg_src.GetLayerByName(layer_name)
    layer_defn = gpkg_layer.GetLayerDefn()
    for i in range(layer_defn.GetFieldCount()):
        fieldDefn = layer_defn.GetFieldDefn(i)
        fieldName = slugify(fieldDefn.GetName(), separator='_')
        fieldDefn.SetName(fieldName)
```

However, after updating the fields the changes are not retained if I reopen the gpkg - the names have reverted back to what they were before.

I am opening the file with `update=True`. I also tried to call `SyncToDisk` on the Layer.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoPackage is a SQLite database and renaming columns in SQLite is not trivial. Traditionally it required to do all this (from https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-rename-column/)

> First, start a transaction.
>
> Second, create a new table whose structure
> is the same as the original one except for the column that you want to rename.
>
> Third, copy data from the original table to the new table.
>
> Fourth, drop the original table.
>
> Fifth, rename the new table to the original table. Finally, commit the transaction.

GDAL has for some time had an own SQL function to help with renaming and SQLite itself has now native support for standard SQL way of `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN ... TO ...`

You can find Python code for renaming from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_gpkg.py

Essential lines:

```
ogr.Open(dbname, update=1)
    ds.ExecuteSQL('ALTER TABLE "weird2\'layer""name" RENAME COLUMN "foo" TO "bar"')
```

Some changes to SQLite schema may get so complicated that it is faster and at least easier to avoid errors by creating a new GeoPackage with desired structure instead of making manual fixes. See the diagram with 11 steps in https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/.

Comment: Thanks for this. I used the ExecuteSQL command as you suggested and it has worked. I'm still a bit confused about why SetName doesn't do the trick if you are able to clarify. I initially thought copying the layer after using the SetName had worked but none of the data was saved so I have updated my question to remove that.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the GDAL gpkg driver well enough to say why SetName didn't work. I just know that the ExecuteSQL should work and is preferred because it knows to do all the difficult tasks automatically. See also https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47012 about the difficulties when ALTER TABLE is not utilized.